# What is the syntax for a stop message when no data

Tags: r, error-handling

I am importing some data in to R and want the code to stop running if there is no file or there is no data in the file. I'm using base R and readxl. Please can you help with the syntax?

I've tried

`if (dim(Llatest) == NULL) {stop('STOP NO DATA')}`

`if (dim(Llatest)[1] == 0) +   stop('STOP NO DATA')}`

`if (isTRUE(dim(Llatest) == NULL)) {stop('STOP NO DATA')}`

Some data imported from Sep19import.xlsx

```
ID  Code    Received    Actioned    Decision
1   123 Jul 01 2019 Sep 02 2019 Hold
2   456 Jul 11 2019 Sep 13 2019 No action
3   789 Nov 26 2018 Sep 25 2019 Investigate
4   321 Sep 12 2019 Sep 12 2019 Await decision
5   654 Aug 30 2019 Sep 26 2019 Hold
6   987 Feb 22 2019 Sep 02 2019 Investigate
```

## Obtain list of files for import

`LFiles <- list.files(path = "C:/Projects/Sep/code", pattern = "*import.xlsx", full.names = TRUE)`
***I wish to stop here if LFiles is empty

## Identify the latest file

`Llatest <- subset(LFiles, LFiles == max(LFiles))`

## Extract data from file

`LMonthly <- read_excel(Llatest)`

***I wish to stop here if LMonthly is empty

Error Messages received - no non-missing arguments, returning NA
I expect the output to be 'STOP NO DATA'

Comment: `stop` with `is.null` perhaps? Something like `if(!is.null(iris)) stop("This is null")`? Can use `length/nrow`?

Comment: If you want to check with `NULL` you have to use `is.null`. However, it seems to me that checking the `length` of the object might be better here. So try `if (length(LFiles)==0) stop("STOP NO DATA")`.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas